# Python - Nested Classes (Parent-Child [New to Classes])

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this data

```
{Wednesday : {22 : {Type = x,
                    Temp = x,
                    Speed = x,
                    Direction = x}
             {23 : {Type = x,
                    Temp = x,
                    Speed = x,
                    Direction = x}
```

I am trying to write a class so that I will be able to access it by calling  as an example and that will give me X.

My code so far is this :

```
class Weather(object):
        def __init__(self, wtype, wtemp, wspeed, wdirection):
            self.type = wtype
            self.temp = wtemp
            self.speed = wspeed
            self.direction = wdirection
```

This allows me to get the data when calling upon the date :

```
Wednesday.Temp
>>> 22
```

However I also need to allocate the data by time as well as the date, so when calling `"Wednesday.22.Type"` I get the specific date for that our.

I am new to classes within Python and I'm not quite sure on how to build the class so that I can call on the date, and then the time to get the respective data. I'm assuming that a nested class is needed to have a "parent-child" like relation in the code however I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: `22` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @CodingLambdas would it be better to stick to nested dictionaries?

Comment: I am currently writing an answer.

Comment: So you want to chain attribute calls?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, essentially

Comment: What you are trying to do is conceptionally hard, because nested classes are the wrong tool for simple data storage that you are trying to achieve. Use a pandas Series/dataframe with a Multiindex and you will be fine.

Comment: It might be a good idea to clarify what your input data actually looks like.  Is it already a nested dictionary?  Or is it some text that needs to be parsed?  The example data you have given is mostly syntax errors.

Comment: @PaulCornelius The data was originally sourced from a website using bs4, it is some text that needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although numbers are not considered to be valid identifiers in Python (but that could be funny for trolling: `0 = 1 = 2 = 3 = 42`), things like `_3` are, but are generally considered to be *"private"* attributes by the python community (myself included), so i use `at` followed by the number instead. And I think it would be better to access it like you access a dictionary.

Here is my take on it. Remove the methods if you don't want the associated feature.

```py
class SpecificWeather(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @property
    def type(self):
        return self.data["Type"]

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        return self.data["Temp"]

    @property
    def speed(self):
        return self.data["Speed"]

    @property
    def direction(self):
        return self.data["Direction"]


class Weather(object):
    def __init__(self, data):  # data is the dictionary
        self.data = data

    def __getitem___(self, item):  # for wednesday[22].type
        return SpecificWeather(self.data[item])

    def __getattr__(self, name):  # for wednesday.at22.type
        if name.startswith("at"):
            return SpecificWeather(self.data[int(name[2:])])
        raise AttributeError()

    @property
    def type(self):
        # TODO: Return the average type or something like that

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        # TODO: Return the average temperature or something like that

    @property
    def speed(self):
        # TODO: Return the average speed or something like that

    @property
    def direction(self):
        # TODO: Return the average direction or something like that
```

This solution uses `property` a lot, this has a big advantage: If you change the temperate for 22, `wednesday[22].temperature` will now give you the new value. If you care for performance however, and you use only half of them, then this one can be faster than storing the results, if you access them even multiple times though, this will be a lot slower.

How to use it:

```
wednesday = Weather({
    22: {
        'Type': ...,
        'Temp': 30,
        'Speed': ...,
        'Direction': ...
    },
    23: {
        'Type': ...,
        'Temp': 28,
        'Speed': ...,
        'Direction': ...
    }
})

print(wednesday.at22.temperature)  # gives 30
print(wednesday[23].temperature)  # gives 28
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but could you include an example to demonstrate, I don't fully understand how to use it.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I need, however I do get this error when trying to use this code `print(wednesday[23].temperature)` "TypeError: 'Weather' object does not support indexing"

Comment: @CodingLambdas did you mean to inherit from SpecificWeather?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nope. `SpecificWeather` is the weather for a specific time, while `Weather` is for the whole day, so `Weather` contains more data. But for using `isinstance`, and because they have some pretty similar properties, you could create a `BaseWeather` class.

Comment: @CodingLambdas OH yes I see.

Comment: @CodingLambdas Not a problem with your answer, but a minor point: `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute lookup has already failed.  Therefore your call to `super().__getattr__(name)` is certain to fail and should be replaced by `raise AttributeError`.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Your right, I just forgot the name and was to lazy to look it up.